# trouble with playframework Promise when streaming events come in

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I love the playframework 1.2.5 Promise concept but I am having a bit of trouble as I read their code for Promise.  For one, it only accepts a "single" result.  While I could create multiple Promise objects, I would not know how many to create.  I send one request and I get back 1000's of chunks.  As these chunks come in, I want to add them to a queue.  I first tried to subclass the Promise object with on that had a List but I can't reset the invoked variable as I wanted a simple method...

```
 public synchronized List<T> resetAndGetResponses()
```

such that

1. I can re-use the Promise over and over while stuff keeps coming in
2. No one that uses this client on our project has to worry about synchronization

Maybe I should just modify the playframework so invoked is protected.  any ideas appreciated though?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use on promise per chunk and have a code similar to the one shown in the doc : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/asynchronous#HTTPresponsestreaming

Comment: no, I have done that before and that example is so the "server" can "send back" chunks to the client.  I need something to "receive" chunks from another server.  That example shows the CSVGenerator.nextdataChunk which has nothing to do with http on the receive end.....I ended up modifying the playframework to support this new use case.